# How can I hang up on only one party when using call waiting?

Tags: htc-thunderbolt, call-waiting

I have an HTC Thunderbolt. When I use call waiting, I can't hang up on one line without the phone hanging up both calls. How can I hang up on just one party?

Answer (score 1):

Switch to the call you want to end, hit end. A few seconds later the other caller will "call you back", which is actually just the other call resuming. It's weird, but that's how cdma signaling works. "it's not a bug, it's a feature"